# @Url.Action with parameter

Tags: jquery, dialog, url-action

I'm tring tyUrl.Action to  need to pass multiple parameters to

I need to load dialog box with multiple parameters with url.action. How can I do that? I tried few ways but nothing worked:

```
diag.load('@Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new {para1=val,para2=val2})', '', function () {
}
```

Need less to mention, all values would be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, that should work.  It does however rely on the fact that you have that controller action's route set-up with para1 and para2 specifically.  It needs to know how to build up the url from these bits, so it uses the routing table.